# For some reason I'm unable to import office365.sharepoint.file

Tags: python, pandas, sharepoint, office365

I'm trying to import office365.sharepoint.file and I keep getting the error

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'office365.sharepoint.file'

I'm stuck because I haven't been able to find out whether the method used to import it has changed.

Any help would be appreciated

````
import io
from office365.sharepoint.file import File 

response = File.open_binary(ctx, relative_url)

#save data to BytesIO stream
bytes_file_obj = io.BytesIO()
bytes_file_obj.write(response.content)
bytes_file_obj.seek(0) #set file object to start

#read file into pandas dataframe
df = pd.read_excel(bytes_file_obj)```


---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-ce2948d5390a> in <module>
      1 import pandas as pd
      2 import io
----> 3 from office365.sharepoint.file import File
      4 
      5 response = File.open_binary(ctx, relative_url)

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'office365.sharepoint.file'```
````

Comment: Okay. Were you able to import it before? If not, why do you think you should be able to do it now? If you did have it installed before, then you need to explain about how your Python installation is set up. But either way, I think you should try https://superuser.com instead. It seems like the problem is about using your computer (getting the package installed properly), not about writing code.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel this is the first time I'm using it but I have installed the packages. I'll give superuser.com a try either way

Comment: Attempted to do the same thing on my Macbook and the program still wouldn't work. I'm wondering whether I have installed the correct libraries @KarlKnechtel

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found that one has to path the full URL to File, not just the path:

`from office365.sharepoint.files.file import File`

Answer (score 1):

Try to install the o365 library. It would solve your problem.